# C#: When performing XSLT: The process cannot access the file

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, csc, system.xml

I'm implementing XSLT using C#.

In my working directory, I have data.xml file.xsl, and I want to apply the XSLT defined by file.xsl on data.xml, in order to get data.html

**xslt.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

class XSLT__
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load(args[0]);
        xslt.Transform(args[1], args[1].Replace("xml","html"));
    } 
}
```

And I have a script with the following commands:

```
calculations_script > data.xml
csc xslt.cs
xslt.exe file.xsl data.xml
```

I'm generating xslt.exe on the fly since the executable won't work on every platform this script will run in.

I'm always getting the following error:

**Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file /my/folder/data.xml because it is being used by another process**

What can I do?

Comment: well.... *is* it being used by another process?

Comment: @Mugen Note that you can use the Sysinternals tools [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to help answer Marc's question.

Comment: @RB. thanks for the tools. As much as I can find, It's not used by another process, and nor should it. I didn't mention it, but data.xml is created in that first line of the script, I don't see how it could be used by another process

Comment: I found the problem, seems like it was with my script: The file generated was lacking the 'xml' extension, and Windows wasn't handling it very well. Thanks for the help!